# Zend 2 - DB - Escape value without quoting it

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-db

I'm looking for a clean way to escape value for SQL query **without** quoting it.

Let's say i have a value `It's cool`. Now I would like to simply get escaped string `It\'s cool`, just like when using for example `mysqli_real_escape_string()` function for `mysqli` driver.

The problem is that all `Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform` interface's quoting methods adds single quotes to the value which means I get `'It\s cool'`.

Simplest way I found to do this is to trim quotes after usage of `quoteValue()` method.

```
$raw = "It's cool";
$quoted  = $this->db->platform->quoteValue($raw);
$final = trim($quoted, "'");
```

But it's of course a dirty solution and I don't want it to be like this in every place I need **escaped-only** value.

Is there any clean way to do this simple thing in Zend2?

Comment: What is this quoting for? If it's for usage in an SQL statement, then you're going about it wrong... you don't do manual escaping anymore, not with prepared statemeents & placeholders available.

Comment: It's not standard SQL syntax. It's for SphinxSE. I need part of quoted parameter to be escaped and other part of it not. For example SphinxSE accepts `;` signs as a separator inside `query` parameter value which can't be escaped, but it has to be escaped in first "escaped" part of whole value.

Comment: there's addslashes(), but it's a highly unsafe function because it's not unicode aware.

Comment: No it's not. I repeat once again: escaped part of whole parameter value needs to be fully escaped. `addslashes()`  is not designed for database escaping.

Comment: Don't use DB functions for escaping something that isn't going into a DB. Perhaps the answer here will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7169992/escaping-special-characters-in-sphinxse

Comment: It is going to DB and it needs to be escaped since otherwise SQL Injection is possible. I don't want to use prepared statements and escaping additional chars as it's suggested in the question you linked is a bit different thing. On thing is to prevent SQL Injection and another is to prevent - let's say - SphinxSE parameter injection.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE posts set comment = :value where id = :id";
$data = ['value' => "It's cool", 'id' => 123];
$stmt= $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->createStatement($sql);
$stmt->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($data);
```